# How can I quickly tell how Haskell parses an expression? Is it possible to print the expression with parenthesis around every non-leaf AST node?

Tags: haskell, operator-precedence, ghci

Sometimes I run into expressions full of different operators and I have no idea how they get parsed. I know that I can ask GHCi information about an operator with `:i`, but having to look at multiple operators and apply their precedence and associativity to reconstruct it in my mind feels quite hard.

Is there any simpler way to understand it?

###### Example

For example take this valid Haskell expression:

```hs
7 ¤ 2 ⏆ 4 ⏆ 3 ¤ 1 ♂ 3 ♂ 2
```

And assume that the precedence of those operators is:

- infixl 6 ¤
- infixl 7 ⏆
- infixr 8 ♂

###### Question

Is it possible to ask GHCi to print it out like this?

```hs
(7 ¤ ((2 ⏆ 4) ⏆ 3)) ¤ (1 ♂ (3 ♂ 2))
```

Are there any other ways to quickly get an idea of how that expression works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define an expression type, use those operators to construct an expression, and pretty-print it.

```
-- E.hs
module E where

data Exp
  = Leaf String
  | Binop Exp String Exp

pretty :: Exp -> String
pretty (Leaf l) = l
pretty (Binop l o r) = "(" ++ pretty l ++ " " ++ o ++ " " ++ pretty r ++ ")"

instance Show Exp where
  show = pretty

type B a = a -> a -> a

binop :: String -> B Exp
binop o l r = Binop l o r

instance Num Exp where
  (+) = binop "+"
  (-) = binop "-"
  (*) = binop "*"
  fromInteger = Leaf . show  -- interprets literals as expressions

infixl 6 ¤
infixl 7 ⏆
infixr 8 ♂

(¤), (⏆), (♂) :: B Exp
(¤) = binop "¤"
(⏆) = binop "⏆"
(♂) = binop "♂"

example :: Exp
example = 7 ¤ 2 ⏆ 4 ⏆ 3 ¤ 1 ♂ 3 ♂ 2
```

```
$ ghci E.hs
> 7 ¤ 2 ⏆ 4 ⏆ 3 ¤ 1 ♂ 3 ♂ 2
((7 ¤ ((2 ⏆ 4) ⏆ 3)) ¤ (1 ♂ (3 ♂ 2)))
```

---

With the above solution, you have to re-define all operators, looking up and copying their precedence levels manually.

Another way is to use Template Haskell to get the actual AST and pretty-print it.

```
-- T.hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module T where

import Language.Haskell.TH

pretty :: Exp -> String
pretty (LitE l) = pprint l
pretty (InfixE (Just x) (VarE n) (Just y)) = "(" ++ pretty x ++ " " ++ nameBase n ++ " " ++ pretty y ++ ")"
pretty e = error ("pretty: unhandled " ++ show e)

prettify :: Q Exp -> Q Exp
prettify q = [| putStrLn |] `appE` fmap (LitE . StringL . pretty) q
```

Make sure to enable the `TemplateHaskell` extension.

```
$ ghci -XTemplateHaskell E.hs T.hs
> :m E T
> $(prettify [| 7 ¤ 2 ⏆ 4 ⏆ 3 ¤ 1 ♂ 3 ♂ 2 |])
((7 ¤ ((2 ⏆ 4) ⏆ 3)) ¤ (1 ♂ (3 ♂ 2)))
```